# Как установить шаблон win32 для Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

Хочу начать знакомство с формами, но не могу установить необходимы шаблон. Облазил уже весь инсталлер, не вижу ничего похожего. ПОдскажите пжалуйста, а то я скорее всего что-то упустил?

Comment: Следует установить пакет для разработки классических приложений Windows.

Comment: Проблема еще в том, что если я создаю классическое приложение windows, то, когда выбираю опцию "добавить элемент", не могу там найти windows форму, хотя во всех гайдах на ютубе такое есть

Comment: Так может вам нужны WinForms? В классические приложениях нет никаких форм, разве что диалоги да MFC. Приведите конкреные шаблоны, которые "во всех гайдах на ютубе такое есть".

Comment: @VTT Верояно, речь о шаблоне WinForms для С++/CLI, которые MS убрали из стандартной поставки в новых версиях студии. "Гайды на ютюбе", видимо, просто слегка устарели.